# NPE when startForeground

Tags: android, foreground-service

NPE reported in crashlytics only for Android O and above. I just startForegroundService and the service startForground in onCreate method and the NPE happened.

In crashlytics it happened when `startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID_TOOLBAR, mNotification);`

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    buildNotification();
    startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID_TOOLBAR, mNotification);
}
```

> Unable to create service ToolbarService: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int com.android.server.am.UidRecord.curProcState' on a null object reference

Comment: Have you set up notification channels by the time of calling of startForeground ?

Comment: Would love to hear if you ever made any progress on this. Am facing the same issue.. In my case it's when the app is re-installed.

Comment: I am also facing the same issue, @user3162215 were you able to resolve it ?

Comment: any solution?...

Comment: I only see SM-T595 devices with Android 9 affected. Any others?

Comment: I also acknowledge this only under Android 9, but on multiple Samsung devices

Comment: @AlexeyOzerov I got this issue reported on a Zebra Technologies TC77 device running Android 8.1. so it's not specific to Samsung

Comment: Happening to me, any solution?

Answer (score -4):

Probably `mNotification` value is `null`. You need to analyze your code to figure out why and when. This code snippet is to short to perform any analysis.

Comment: Nope, mNotification is not null when buildNotification(); is called

Comment: So if `NOTIFICATION_ID_TOOLBAR` is not `null` too, then there will be `null` somewhere inside `startForeground(...)` method, but I have no idea where. It needs to be debugged.